# As3 flixel - mouse issue with external swf

Tags: actionscript-3, input, flixel

I finally got externally loaded swfs working (for menus) in my flixel game. Only problem is,  I'm using FlxG.stage.addChild(mClip); which seems to place the movie clip on top of everything else... including FlxG.mouse. Anyone know of a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this func to bring it to front.

```
    public static function bringToFront(obj:*):void
    {
        obj.parent.setChildIndex(obj, (obj.parent.numChildren - 1));
    }
```